# Unique DB entry to the user

Tags: django

I have a model that takes in a listname. I only want the list name to disable duplicates per user. Currently, a user cannot enter "recipes" twice, but if another user doesn't have a "recipe" list name, they can't enter it either because the field is unique. Is it possible to make the listname only unique to the currently logged in user?

## MODEL

```
class newlist(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', default = "/media/profiles/default.jpg")
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='list_name', default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

Comment: "unique to the currently logged in user" or "unique for each user"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the models `Meta` class `unique_together`. You can find the excellent documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

```
class newlist(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together=('user','list_name')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', default = "/media/profiles/default.jpg")
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='list_name', default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            return super(newlist,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        except IntegrityError: # This is raised if the object can't be saved.
            # Your error handling code
            from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
            raise PermissionDenied()
```

Comment: fantastic! Is there a way to render a form error for duplicates instead of a django error page?